# Deploying multiple app together

Tags: capistrano

I have two apps configured to deploy using capistrano and they both deploy fine individually, but I would like to make releases where both apps need to be deployed together.

If there a solution out there to deploy multiple capistrano deploys together and select branches?

I've tried caphub but it's not working for me, I get this:

```
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Proc:0x007f870bf5a8e0>
```

I could have a bash script to deploy all, but is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Basically you choose 1 main repo and have the rest as submodules, this way Capistrano only pulls from one git repo = atomic deploy.

It won't actually merge the repos, each one will have its own commit history as before.
Submodules' code will appear under main module's root folder.

So if all your apps are to be on the same server, this could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a better approach if You want to keep the configurațion for Capistrano inside your projects but still be able to deploy them în paralell .

This works even if the two projects use different versions of Capistrano ( 2.x and 3.x )

You just need to do four simple steps:

1) Run this command from terminal în any directory . But make sure You have ruby >= 2.2.

`gem install capistrano_multiconfig_parallel -v 2.4.O`

2) create a YAML file în your home directory ( /home/username)  with name 'multi_cap.yml'

3) Read this readme https://github.com/bogdanRada/capistrano_multiconfig_parallel and put all configurațions in that. File.

4) Run your deploy în paralel as showned în the Readme.

This gem allows You to deploy a application to multiple stages at the same time .

And You can specify different branches at runtime.

But before You do all of this. You need to make sure that each task won't use a resource ( file) that other task might use also or you'll find yourself în a deadlock.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Disclaimer: i am the owner of the gem :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that this gem js also compatibile with Caphub. So if You prefer using a centralized system this will work with that too :)

Comment: And there are other features available like synchronizing the deploys to wait for one another until they get to same state and then resume the deploy. And it also automatically detects if the deploy didn't worked and tries to rollback it.

Comment: Besides this it can handle not only deploys but can run any Capistrano task în parallel.

Comment: Please check the Readme for more features :)